# 32 bit colors seem different

Tags: android, image, colors, photoshop

I'm uploading an app on the play store and I realize that google wants a 32 bits icon. So I realized that the icon I built with photoshop is 8 bits. I can easily get the 16 bit version as well, but with 32 bits I have a problem of getting the background color I want. My background color is burgundy and on photoshop, with 8 bits or 16 bits I can obtain the color using this hex value #800020 or these rgb values (128, 0, 32) however when I try to make a 32 bit icon and I try to select that color I get so many more confusing panels and the 128, 0, 32 rgb values isn't burgundy but some sort of pink color. Does anyone know how to get the equivalent of 128, 0, 32 in a 32 bit version? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Check this software here - http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/download.html

Comment: Now that you mentioned GIMP, here's a question about the same problem you got - > http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/topic/51586-creating-32bit-png-image-with-alpha-channel-transparency/